# Can anyone tell me what this statue bar icon is from?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

Can anyone tell me what this status bar icon is for? Not the black message icon on the left, but the white text bubble on the right. It looks like either an alert triangle in the bottom corner but definitely looks different than the normal text notification.
[image]

Comment: If you expand the notification drawer, is there an app/message/notification associated with it?